# Is devise compatible with declarative_authorization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization, devise

Just asking whenever **devise** authentication mechanism for Rails does not conflict with **declarative_authorization**.

Maybe someone tried this combo and can share their knowledge, so I and other coders do not waste time trying to tie these ones up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it is. I am currently using both in my project now.

Everything works seamlessly. Just configure devise and declarative_authorization as documented and set this in your `application_controller.rb` (which is also available in declarative_authorization docs)

```
before_filter :set_current_user
 protected
 def set_current_user
   Authorization.current_user = current_user
 end
```

`current_user` is a helper method that is provided by devise.

Hope that helps.

**Note**: I am using Rails 3 beta, with the latest devise and declarative_authorization.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used devise myself, but I have some experience with declarative_authorization.

It shouldn't be a problem to use it with devise as it doesn't care at all about authentication. Declarative_authorization only needs the User model to have a `role_symbols` method and otherwise it doesn't matter what the model really does.

Comment: Not that simple. Infact declarative_authorization is not compatible with Authlogic.

Comment: Why not? I'm using declarative_authorization with authlogic now and didn't have any problems.

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: I'm still on 2.3.5. What are the problems when using both libraries with Rails 3?

Comment: For those coming across this, I've been using Authlogic with declarative_authorization with Rails 3 for a while now and have had no problems at all.